# Как вывести/вызвать глобальную переменную из функции в другой функции

Tags: python

У меня есть 2 функции. Необходимо напечатать/вызвать переменную в другой функции.

```
def first_function(some):
    global x
    
def second_function(some):
    print (x)
```

Comment: Вопросы на русском стеке надо задавать на русском языке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def first_function(some):
    global x
    x = 42

def second_function(some):
    global x
    print (x)
```

`global` не создаёт переменную, а объясняет интерпретатору, в какой области видимости её искать.

P.S. Использовать `global` - плохой стиль, старайтесь передавать аргументы в функции явным образом, либо передавать параметры в класс при его инициализации, чтобы потом использовать эти параметры внутри класса без явной их передачи каждый раз.

Comment: Во второй функции, кстати, `global` не обязателен, т.к. только чтение.

Comment: @вася Да, хотя проще уж указать, а то потом ещё вопросы будут, когда понадобится всё же изменить переменную )

Comment: мне кажется этот ответ можно значительно улучшить, показав наиболее идиоматический пример того, как это правильно делается без использования глобальных переменных)

Comment: @MaxU Да надо просто дать ссылку на один из дубликатов этого вечного вопроса, но мне не до того ))

Answer (score -1):

```
def first_function():
    first_function.x = 42

def second_function():
    print(first_function.x)

# second_function() # ERROR
# first_function()

first_function()
second_function()
```

Comment: Это плохой способ, не нужно так делать никогда.

Comment: @insolor Да с global тоже плохой способ, что уж там ))  А в данном случае проще вообще из функции число вернуть без этих всех заморочек

Comment: @insolor чем он хуже глобальных переменных? Порядок вызова хуже, scope лучше

Comment: @вася, потому что нигде не задекларировано, что в функции вдруг откуда-то появилось это поле. Вообще добавление чужеродных полей в объекты (добавление полей извне) - плохая практика.

Comment: @insolor в функции и задекларировано. Если из другой функции надо вызывать что-то из первой, то логично предположить, что вторая должна знать всё о первой. Конечно, это плохая практика, но `global` тоже плохая.

Comment: @вася вот именно, что вторая функция вдруг почему-то должна знать что у первой функции что-то в кишках поменялось, и она стала не функцией, а каким-то объектом-франкенштейном. Это нарушение принципа инкапсуляции по сути.

Comment: @insolor ну так глобальные переменные тоже нарушают

Comment: @вася глобальные переменные инкапсулированы на уровне модуля. Можно считать, что это поля объекта модуля (фактически это так и есть). Иногда их можно использовать. То что вы предлагаете в своем ответе - никогда не нужно использовать.

Comment: @insolor ну а это поле объекта функции тогда, уже чем модуль. [Тоже используют](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279561).

Comment: @вася, по ссылке костыль, как эмулировать статические переменные внутри функций. Так делать не нужно. Я пожалуй поставлю минус, и закончу этим дискуссию.